# What is the difference between the VSCode settings `editor.wordBasedSuggestions` and `editor.suggest.showWords`?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If both are enabled, the editor will offer arbitrary text from the current document in auto-completion suggestions, if either one is disabled, it won't, so why are there two settings that apparently control the same thing?

`editor.wordBasedSuggestions`:

[image: editor.wordBasedSuggestions]

`editor.suggest.showWords`:

[image: editor.suggest.showWords]

Answer (score 0):

The setting `editor.wordBasedSuggestions` controls whether the text editor locates all words in the document that are not recognized as identifiers (variables, constants, classes, etc.), operators, or keywords of the current syntax language and adds them as text-entries to the list of auto-complete items. If disabled, no words are added and thus no words are suggested.

The setting `editor.suggest.showWords` controls whether items on the auto-complete list that are tagged as type `text` are suggested for completion. If disabled, they are not, even if they would be on the list.

So in the first case they aren't even added to the list and in the second case they aren't suggested, hence disabling either one makes the suggestions disappear.

But why are there two settings to begin with? Because they don't do the same thing.

If you disable `editor.wordBasedSuggestions`, then no words from the current document are added as text items to the list but that doesn't mean that no text items are found on that list. Other parts of the app or extension can still add entries marked as type text that don't originate from the current document and those would still be suggested, even if `editor.wordBasedSuggestions` is disabled. E.g. those may be static text snippets, text items shared between different users, or provided by some online service.

And if you disable `editor.suggest.showWords`, the text suggestions are not offered by the editor, but they can still be on the list and can still be used in other places in the app  or by an extensions that somehow uses the content of the auto-complete list for other purposes.